CORS policy on loading tensorflow model

I am getting this error when trying to load the model.
the error started happening 10 hours back. everything was working fine till then.
I tried creating a wrapper API that wraps this:


router.get("/modelWrapper", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("********** poseDetector WRAPPER *************");
    const response = await fetch('https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/movenet/frameworks/tfJs/variations/singlepose-lightning/versions/4/model.json?tfjs-format=file&tfhub-redirect=true');
    
    console.log("********** RESPONSE WRAPPER *************");
    // Check if response is successful
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch resource');
    }

    // Get response body as JSON
    const data = await response.json();

    // Add CORS headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    console.log("********** HEADER WRAPPER *************");
    // Send response back to frontend
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
  }
});



I am able to get the models but fetching weights fails.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I had the same problem (also since very recently)
It seems that the host does not allow requests from other domains anymore. Maybe in order to save some traffic.
It may work for you to provide the model from your own server.
You can download it here:
https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/movenet/tfJs/singlepose-lightning
Make sure to select the right platform (tensorflow.js in my case) and the right model (single lighning in my case).
